# Dialogs on Sasung devices (One UI) aligned to bottom of screen

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, samsung-mobile, android-dialog, android-compose-dialog

I have two functions to show dialogs in my app, one is to show a dialog with a progress bar (using the `Dialog` component) and the second one is to show a dialog with buttons (using the `AlertDialog` component). I'm using `compose 1.3.2` and `androidx.compose.material 1.4.0-alpha03`.

Everything is fine, the dialog is located in the center of the screen on **all devices except Samsung** with One UI.

On Samsungs, dialogs are aligned **to the bottom** of the screen.

I found such an [article](https://developer.samsung.com/one-ui/comp/dialog.html) and it turned out that this is normal behavior for critical dialogs and dialogs with a choice or confirmation, however, they recommend displaying progress dialogs in the center of the screen.

How can I align my Dialog so that it is centered on all devices?

Here is the code of my progress dialog

```
@Composable
private fun ProgressDialog(state: ProgressDialogState) {
    Dialog(
        onDismissRequest = state.onCancel ?: {},
        properties = DialogProperties(dismissOnBackPress = false, dismissOnClickOutside = false)
    ) {
        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(80.dp)
                .background(AppTheme.colors.background, shape = AppShapes.medium)
        ) {
            CircularProgressIndicator(color = AppTheme.colors.primary)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only solution I found - replace Dialog with custom implementation - just dimmed fullscreen box with content.

```
@Composable
fun ProgressDialog(state: AppState.ProgressDialogState) {
    val show = remember(state) { state.isShowing }

    // Dialog replaced with Box due to bottom position of dialogs on some Samsung devices
    if (show) Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.scrim.copy(alpha = .55f))
            .clickable(
                interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                indication = null,
                onClick = {
                    // click interceptor
                }
            ),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {

        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(80.dp)
                .background(AppTheme.colors.bgPrimary, shape = AppShapes.medium)
        ) {
            CircularProgressIndicator(color = AppTheme.colors.buttonPrimary)
        }
    }
}
```